# How to represent a 5 letter string as digit?

Tags: java

I want to create a numerical representation of 5 letter codes. The codes may have 1-5 letters or digits.

The number must of course be **unique**. It is not absolutely necessairy that those numbers can be converted back to the ascii.

Thus I need digits from `0` to `ZZZZZ`

The resulting number size should be as small as possible.

I started with the following, but it's not quite what I want:

```
String a="ZZZZZZ";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
   System.out.print(a.charAt(i)-'A'+1);
}

ZZZZZZ=262626262626
000000=-16-16-16-16-16-16
```

Comment: why not map each letter to its index in the alphabet? A=1, B=2 and so on.

Comment: do you want it to be case sensitive?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start by enumerating all possible "digits" of your number:

- Ten decimal digits `0` through `9`
- Twenty six letters `A` through `Z`

You have 36 possible "digits" for five positions, so the max number is 36<sup>5</sup>=60,466,176. This number fits in an `int`.

You can make this number by calling `Integer.parseInt`, and passing a radix of 36:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("ABZXY", 36)); // 17355958
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/SGdTDh)

Comment: Would the same apply if I'd only have uppercase letters? Or would there then be a better conversation method?

Comment: @membersound If you drop decimal digits, you could make it more economical by using base-26 conversion. However, you would have to write conversion yourself - essentially, subtract `A`, and add next digit by `val = val*26 + c - 'A'` in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that `A134Z` is already a number; it is only printed in Base-36 representation!

Albeit being just one sentence, the above should give you all you need to know to translate any 5-character string with 0-9 and A-Z into a number (and back).

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution - if letters are case insensitive is to use radix of 36 - full alphabet plus 10 digits. That way you get both functions for free - converting from string to long and from long to string like this:

```
long numericCode = Long.parseLong("zzzzz", 36); // gives 60466175
String stringCode = Long.toString(numericCode, 36); // gives "zzzzz"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the string as a number in base36 (where A=10, B=11 ... Z=35). This way, you will use exactly the numbers from 0 to 36^5-1, and each will be used exactly once.